# Why is Windows Update suddenly failing with error 0x80244019?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, wsus

Since installing updates yesterday, one of our 2008 R2 servers refuses to connect to our WSUS again and, instead, reports the unknown error `0x80244019`. Connecting to the official Windows Update repository works without any issues. The problem happens only with our local WSUS.

[The Windows support website on the error](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Windows-Update-error-80070422-80244019-or-8DDD0018) suggests:

> If you receive one of these errors while downloading updates, the most common cause is a computer virus that has turned off Windows Update, or another service on your computer that is needed by Windows Update.

I'm gonna vote *No* on that one.

My `WindowsUpdate.log` shows the following:

```
2012-09-13  13:00:52:738     892    5c0 PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2012-09-13  13:00:52:738     892    5c0 PT    + ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://SRV-PDC/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2012-09-13  13:00:52:769     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2012-09-13  13:00:52:769     892    5c0 PT  Initializing simple targeting cookie, clientId = a6c96caf-d9ca-4f31-a003-827e7089ff64, target group = Server, DNS name = srv-exchange.porta.haseke.de
2012-09-13  13:00:52:769     892    5c0 PT    Server URL = http://SRV-PDC/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: GetAuthorizationCookie failure, error = 0x80244019, soap client error = 10, soap error code = 0, HTTP status code = 404
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: Failed to initialize Simple Targeting Cookie: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: PopulateAuthCookies failed: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: RefreshCookie failed: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: RefreshPTState failed: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: Sync of Updates: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 PT  WARNING: SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed: 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 Agent     * WARNING: Failed to synchronize, error = 0x80244019
2012-09-13  13:00:52:957     892    5c0 Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80244019
```

And, actually, another support article caught my eye: 
[You cannot download updates when you access the Windows Update Web site from a Windows XP-based computer that is behind a firewall or a proxy server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896226)

That article refers to XP, but I had to recently tweak with the WinHTTP settings on that server to resolve yet another issue (Please see the support article [Error message when you import a third-party certificate into Exchange Server 2010: "The certificate status could not be determined because the revocation check failed"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979694/en-us) for further details).

I fixed that access problem by running:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http=www-proxy:8080" bypass-list="*.domain.example.com"
```

So, I'm assuming Windows Update uses WinHTTP as well, and my changes prevent it from working properly. But even after adjusting my `bypass-list` to `"*.domain.example.com;<local>"`, Windows Update refuses to function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a reboot was all that was needed after adjusting the `bypass-list`, which **must** contain `<local>` so the WinHTTP proxy is bypassed for your local WSUS installation:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http=www-proxy:8080" bypass-list="*.domain.example.com;<local>"
```

Alternatively, if you're already setting the correct proxy in IE (through group policy, for example), you can simply *import* those settings into WinHTTP:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

To *inspect* your own current WinHTTP proxy settings, run [`netsh winhttp show proxy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_7).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solution.  This definitely guided me to my solution.  We use a pac file to configure IE so I had to run the following command:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 192.168.1.105:3128 "<localhost>"
```

Rebooted and windows update started working again.

Thanks

Comment: *edit "" should have had <local> surrounded by quotes

Comment: That command circumvents the pac file